# Why do I get a stack overflow exception?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Below is a simple test program that throws a `StackOverflowException` when `Equals` is called. I expected the generic `Equals` that I got from object to call my `IEquatable<MyClass>.Equals`, but it does not, it calls itself instead. Why? The parameter type seems ok. Why does it call the generic version in the first place? I am confused.

```
using System;

namespace consapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass x0 = new MyClass("x0");
            MyClass x1 = new MyClass("x");

            Console.WriteLine(x1.Equals(x0));
        }

    }

    internal class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public MyClass(string s) { this.Name = s; }
        public override bool Equals(object x) { return this.Equals(x as MyClass); }
        public override int GetHashCode() { return this.Name.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode(); }
        bool IEquatable<MyClass>.Equals(MyClass x) { return x != null && this.Name == x.Name; }
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem I see is that you haven't defined the Name property in the MyClass class. Define a member variable to store a string representing a name, then get/set it using the Name property.

Comment: On a side note, you probably don't need to explicitly override IEquatable; it will overload just fine with the Object version and you generally want to expose the more specific Equals for clients of your class.

Comment: @Dan: i am not sure what you mean. i understand the first part where you say that i can use my object override implementation as IEquatable implementation as well, but i do not understand what you mean after that. the second part seems to contradict the beginning of the sentence :)

Comment: if you simply remove the `IEquatable<MyClass>.` before your method (making it a non-explicit override), clients of your code can use either method.  If they provide a MyClass parameter, it will automatically use the more specific overload (the method taking the MyClass parameter).  Any other type will go through the Object Equals override.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IEquatable.Equals` is implemented explicitly. You have to cast the class to the interface first to use an explicit implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object x) 
{ 
  return (this as IEquatable).Equals(x as MyClass); 
}
```

Otherwise it will keep on calling itself in an infinite recursion, yielding in a StackoverflowException eventually.

Comment: thanks. i did not know that explicitly implemented interface methods cannot be called in the way similar to non interface methods.

Comment: this is the reason you use explicit implementations - so you can have different interfaces implementing the same method name.

Comment: In this case though, there's no other method with the same signature, and it will make `x.Equals(y)` where both `x` and `y` are `MyClass` needlessly go through the less specific version. I would change the `Equals(MyClass)` to be implicit and change the `Equals(object)` back to how it was.

Comment: This is completely true, but it wasn't the concern of the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

`public override bool Equals(object x) { return this.Equals(x as MyClass); }`
The above line is causing it.

You will have to change it to

```
public override bool Equals(object x) 
{ 
    return ((IEquatable<MyClass>)this).Equals(x as MyClass); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call Object's Equals in your Equal override, you should call base.Equals, not this.Equals.

And note that Object's Equals just compares the references, not the contents.

Comment: this is not the cause of the error here, he wants to call the explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public override bool Equals(object x) {
    Console.Write("equals! ");
    return this.Equals(x as MyClass);

}
```